# Htaccess rewrite/redirect .php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I tried to look for an answer for my problem, but i'm not secure to have find it.

In my website i actually use this **.htaccess** to rewrite the url:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

#General rewrite condition 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It work correctly, if i write "*www.mysite.com/pagename1*"

But, when i make a link from pagename1 to pagename2 (for ex):

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/pagename2">Link</a>
```

The browser automatically open to "*www.mysite.com/pagename2* **.php**", then it add the file extention.

Q1: How is it possible?

Q2: How i prevent this?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\ /(.*)\.php(\?.*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php
```

Comment: With this if i write "www.mysite.com/pagename1" the result is: "Page not found", but work with .php ext. Not is what i want...
I need a condition that automatically redirect from **../pagename1.php** to **../pagename**